# What is the tense of shared in "when shared?"

Tags: tenses

Consider the sentence "Everything is better when shared with friends."

What is the tense of "shared" in this context? It confuses me because the sentence implies that the sharing has not yet happened, but the word itself seems like it is in past tense form.

I am trying to learn another language and I am having a difficult time translating this sentence.

Comment: *Everything....when [it is] shared...* the subject is implied

Comment: It's the past participle of *share*. HTH. See also: [ell.se].

Comment: It doesn't have a tense: it is not a finite verb. The form is called the "past participle", but that is just its name - it does not mean that it is necessarily past in meaning. A better name might be "passive participle".